# Value of function based on functional analysis

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

$\forall m,n \in N$ and $(m\neq n) $ if $f (m)f (n)=f (m)+3f (n) $ then what is the value of $f(f...f (2))$ f repeated $10$ times. $$\text {Attempt}$$. First I divided both sides by $f (m)f (n) $ assuming that $f (x)\neq 0$.(I dont know whether that assumption is correct.) Then we see that $1=\frac {1}{f (n)}+\frac {3}{f (m)} $. From here we conclude that $f (x) $ is a constant function as $m\neq n$ and many irrationals come in between two natural numbers  still the output is a rational. Thus the function is $f (x)=4$ So the answer is $4^{10} $ but answer sheets say that its $4$. Thank you! Any other way to do it.Do we have to involve limits.

Comment: What is the $I$ set?

Comment: I assume that $fff\dots$ means "$f$ composed with itself $10$ times".  So, if $f$ is constant and never $0$ (so $f(1)=4$) then $f\circ f(2)=f(4)=4$ and so on.  But $f(x)$ identically $0$ also satisfies the functional equation...you'll need more information to rule that out.

Comment: Note;  I don't actually understand your proof that $f(x)$ is constant.  But if you assume that $f(1)\neq 0$ then we easily get $f(1)=4$ and then we remark that $f(m)f(1)=f(m)+3f(1)\implies 3f(m)=12\implies f(m)=4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swapping $m$ and $n$ in initial equiation leads us to 
$$
f(m) + 3f(n) = 3f(m) + f(n) 
$$
or $f(m) = f(n)$ for all $m \neq n$. This means that $f$ is a constant: $f(n) = x$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Substituting $x$ into the initial equation gives
$$
x^2 = 4x.
$$
This equation has one positive integer solution $x = 4$. Thus 
$$
f(2) = 4\\
f(f(2)) = f(4) = 4\\
f(f(f(2))) = f(4) = 4 \\
\dots\\
f^{(10)}(2) = f(4) = 4
$$
where $f^{(k)}$ means $f$ composed with itself $k$ times.

Comment: Yes so then value of that conposed function should be 4/{10} $ right.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar I've edited the answer, does it looks clear now that value of composed $f$ is $4$?